# How to share SQLite in-memory database between two connections in RSQLite in R?

Tags: .net, r, sqlite, in-memory-database, r.net

I'm trying to test a way of sharing large datasets between .NET and R. My current idea is to

1. Open a SQLite database connection from .NET;
2. Write all the data I generated in .NET to this database;
3. Run R in the same process using REngine from [R.NET](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) and connect to the opened SQLite connection using RSQLite.

I already have a prototype working by writing to SQLite database in a temporary file located on the hardisk. It takes about 15 minutes to transfer 50 mil of rows each having 6 columns from .NET to R. However, I want to improve the performance possibly by using an in-memory or temporary SQLite database. I tried starting a SQLite in-memory database in .NET using the following connection string:
`FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared`.
Then R is started in the same process. The following code is executed in R.NET's REngine in a attempt to connect to the same in-memory database. However, I then realized that it is a new in-memory database and the table I originally saved using .NET is not available in this new connection. So the question I'm asking is whether I can connect to a shared in-memory SQLite database with "cache=shared" using RSQLite as mentioned in the [documentation of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)?

```
library(RSQLite)
sqlite = SQLite(shared.cache=TRUE)
conn = dbConnect(sqlite, dbname = ':memory:')
dbListTables(conn)
```

To add on:
I played around with the following code in a standalone R instance and I found that even using the desktop R, I cannot start two connections sharing the same in-memory database. For example, the following conn2 does not have any table in it.

```
library(RSQLite)
sqlite = SQLite(shared.cache=TRUE)
conn = dbConnect(sqlite, dbname = ':memory:')
dbWriteTable(conn, name="Test", test)
dbListTables(conn)
conn2 = dbConnect(sqlite, ':memory:')
dbListTables(conn2)
```

Comment: Could you please share with me that which document the prefix "FullUri" in the conn string " FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared" mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly know about R.net or RSQLite. Anyway the method you are using does not ensure multiple connection to the same in-memory database because scope of memory database is still limited to the closure of last connection object.

According to [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

> The database is automatically deleted and memory is reclaimed when the
> last connection to the database closes.

I ran into same situation today and I am thinking to open a connection which does nothing with following connection string

```
"FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared"
```

and then run the functions (which require shared in-memory database)
and then close above connection. By doing this you don't even have to modify your data access layer, and this will ensure that at least one connection to in-memory database is still open.

Comment: How do you  know to use 'FullUri'? I look through the sqlite doc, I can't find any words talk about what prefix should be used. I firstly use "Data Source=file::memory:?cache=shared", but it's wrong . I then use 'FullUri'. It runs Ok.

Comment: hi @gfan: I don't remember it now however it worked fine when i tested it before answering above question. I had the same issue and I tried different prefixes and endup using above may be I found it on some other forum.